# How to create a 2D spotlight?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, lighting

is it possible to modify my current lighting algorithm that radiates light in all directions to something like:

[image]

Here is is how I am calculating my light in the fragment shader:

```
uniform struct Light
{
    vec4 colour;
    vec3 position;
    vec2 radius;
    float intensity;
} allLights[MAX_LIGHTS];

vec4 calculateLight(Light light)
{
    float aspectRatio = resolution.x / resolution.y; //amt of width / height
    if (aspectRatio > 1.0)
        light.radius.x /= aspectRatio;
    else
        light.radius.x /= aspectRatio;

    vec2 lightDir = fragmentPosition.xy - light.position.xy;
    float lightDistance = length(lightDir);
    if (length(lightDir / light.radius) >= 1.0)
        return vec4(0, 0, 0, 1); //outside of radius make it black

    return light.intensity * (1 - length(lightDir / light.radius)) * light.colour;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with C++?

Comment: Yes it is possible, however you need to know the direction and the angle of the spot light. Discard the light if `dot(normalize(lightDir), normalize(spotDir)) < cos(spotAngle/2)`. See [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you, any suggestions on a good way to calculate the spotDir at a per fragment level given that my lightDir is given by `lightDir = fragmentPosition.xy - light.position.xy`

Comment: @ToM4tto You cannot calculate the direction of the spotlight. The direction of the spotlight is the horizontal green dotted line. It is constant or uniform, like the position, radius and angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to pass in a uniform variable for spotDir, spotAngle (in radians) and modifying the shader to be:

```
vec4 calculateLight(Light light)
{
    float aspectRatio = resolution.x / resolution.y; //amt of width / height
    if (aspectRatio > 1.0)
        light.radius.x /= aspectRatio;
    else
        light.radius.x /= aspectRatio;

    vec2 lightDir = fragmentPosition.xy - light.position.xy;
    float lightDistance = length(lightDir);
    if (length(lightDir / light.radius) >= 1.0)
            return vec4(0, 0, 0, 1); //outside of radius make it black

    if (dot(normalize(lightDir), normalize(light.spotDir.xy)) < cos(light.spotAngle/2))
        return vec4(0, 0, 0, 1); //outside of radius make it black

    return light.intensity * (1 - length(lightDir / light.radius)) * light.colour;
}
```